# Shogun Page Builder images slow to load

Tags: image, optimization, e-commerce, bigcommerce

We are currently running an instance of Shogun page builder integrated with BigCommerce.  IS there a way to optimize image loading from Shogun's CDN?  Even when I import an image onto the page directly from AWS URL, it serves from Shogun CDN and creates a slow time to load for the asset.  Our pages are image-heavy and we'd like to improve the rate at which we serve those to customers and optimize that portion for SEO.  Thanks!

Comment: Try adding lazyload class to that image elements, hope it will adapt default bigcommerce lazy loading feature.

Comment: @CodeBlaze will look into it, do you have an example of that lazyload class syntax?